# rewrite subfolder doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Following rule doesn't work for subfolder rewriting.

```
RewriteRule ^cat/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) cat.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^cat/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) cat.php?id=$1&sid=$2
```

For example With this rule

```
<?php
    $id='News';
    $sid='Politics';
?>
    <a href="cat/<?php echo $id?>/<?php echo $sid?>">..</a>
```

In next page, while echoing `$_GET['sid']`, it doesn't work

```
Notice: Undefined index: sid in ...
```

But this rule

```
RewriteRule ^cat/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) cat.php?id=$1&sid=$2
```

works, if only there is two querystring parameters

```
<a href="cat/<?php echo $id?>/<?php echo $sid?>">..</a>
```

but it generate `ERROR 500` if there is only one parameter

```
<a href="cat/<?php echo $id?>>..</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cat/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ cat.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^cat/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ cat.php?id=$1&sid=$2 [L]
```

Comment: great. Thanks very much